# What are the alternatives to print() and print_r() for debugging purposes?

Tags: 7

I'm working on some code for a custom Drupal 7 module the problem is I'm dealing with many arrays and strings. I have tried to use `print()`, and `print_r()` to output values so I can see what I'm working with, but nothing is printed to the screen.

Is Drupal 7 preventing this from happening? How do other Drupal 7 module developers output values?

For example, in JavaScript I can use `console.log()`; in plain PHP, I would normally use `print()`, `print_r()`, and `echo`.

Comment: It really depends on where your code is as to which debugging methods will work.

Answer (score 5):

It's the same as in other PHP applications with separate V layer - `print` and `print_r`, being directly PHP functions, don't know about anything in View layer of Drupal application. They cannot pass their output to theming chain, cache systems in place and so on. That said, they often works, but that's more a coincidence.

For array inspection, you should either use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or, if you don't have time, patience or skill to set it up, use [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel). Specifically, `dpm`, `dvm`, `dpr` and `dvr` functions will be useful for you. See [this helpful demo page](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html) for details of their use.

TL;DR: Install Devel, replace `print` and `print_r()` calls with `dvm()`. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

print() and echo() are not good for debugging, they are like the document.write() equivalent.

print_r() is like the console.log() equivalent. I prefer to use var_dump() as the output formatting is much better, providing HTML Error Display is turned on in the php.ini file.

To test if the PHP execution is getting to the place where you are debugging put in a die() after the print_r():

```
print_r($your_variable); die('123');
```

Now check if you see '123' on the screen. If the execution stops it's good because you know your debugging code is executing.

You can also install the devel module to use dvm() or dpm(), the difference between them is the formatting. dvm() is formatted similar to print_r() and dpm uses krumo formatting (if that option is set in the Devel settings). These functions will print out in the $messages variable, so make sure the theme's page.tpl file is printing $messages.

If nothing is printed on the screen after a print_r() it could be a number of reasons, here's 2 common reasons I have experienced.

1. There is a PHP error and your php.ini file is set so no errors are displayed. (blank white screen).
2. If the site renders but your debugging code is not displayed, it's possible your code is not included in the execution of the page you refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

What I managed to get working was using:
`drupal_set_message();`
I couldn't get `dpm()`, `dvm()`, or `dpr()` to work after installing the `Devel contrib module`. I was able to print out a variable using `die()` but this also stops all execution and makes Drupal unusable during the test so is not desirable.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know and ill pick the better answer but so far `drupal_set_message();` is the only thing that is working.

I have some json data that i'm currently testing and found the best way to work with it is:

```
$data = json_decode($rawData,true);
foreach($data as $key => $val){
   drupal_set_message($key." = ".$val);
}
```

This way i was able to see each level of the json data and  work on one part of it at a time. There must be a more effective way to see complex data as your building a module.

Comment: Yes, die() will stop the execution, it's just to test if the execution is getting to that part in the code. As for the devel module, you may need to enable some settings to get the debugger functions to work, and the debugging will print out in the $messages variable so the theme page.tpl file has to be calling that variable

Comment: dpm() and drupal_set_message() are equivalent. dpm() does depend on the user having the "access devel information" permission. See https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7

Comment: What settings do i need to change to make devel work?